# Calling a JSON table with id variables that are numbers?

Tags: json, lua

I am decently new to Lua, an I have been trying to work on API calling JSON tables. However, one particular JSON Table I am trying to process has identifiers that start with numbers. For example, one such table looks like this:

```
  "data": {
    "1001": {
        "plaintext": "item title",
        "description": "item description",
        "id": 1001
        }
      }
```

When I try to decode the json file and print "data.1001.id" to the console, for example, I keep getting an error "malformed number near '.1001.id'".

I've looked at other similar questions on this site that say to put it in square brackets, such as "data.[1001].id" or "data.[[1001]].id", but when I do that I get the error " 'name' expected near '[[1001]]'".

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use normal access as an array element []:

```
local json = require("json")
local j=[[ 
{
"data": {
    "1001": {
        "plaintext": "item title",
        "description": "item description",
        "id": 1001
        }
      }
}
]]

local d = json.decode(j)
print(d.data["1001"].description)
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I needed!